# Update JS Variable in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a bot and my goal is to essentially create a counter for my bot every time it is called.  My first thought is to have a variable stored in another file and when the main js file is called it calls a method to update the variable in the other file.  Do I have to use require() or is there another way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either store data in database or a JSON file. In the case of JSON file, the code can be written like this.

```
let fs = require('fs');
let updateCounter = () => {
  fs.readFile('/path/to/counter.json', 'utf8', (er, data) => {
    if(er){
      throw er;
    }
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    data.calledTimes++;
    fs.writeFile('/path/to/counter.json', JSON.stringify(data), er => {
      if(er){
        throw er;
      }          
    });
  });
}
```

#### counter.json

```
{
  "calledTimes": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways so far:

1. in another.js, you `module.exports = {counter:0};` and in main.js you `require(./another).counter++;` (every time the return of require is the original object (nodejs's cache mechanism)
2. put the counter into global scope: `global.counter = 0;`

Hope this helps you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  My initial thought was to put the counter into global scope but I can't figure out how to do that when I don't have an html file.  How do I make it global?

Comment: just go: global.counter = 0;